# Paypal returns "The merchant does not accept payments of this type"

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I integrated Paypal into my mobile APP and I use the REST API Calls. If I pay the ordeers using paypal account, It works succesfully, but if I use Direct Credit Card Payment (when the user doesn't have the paypal account), Paypal System return an error:

"The merchant does not accept payments of this type"

I don't found in my Paypal Dashboard where this payment type could be enabled.

Could you please help me?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Do you verify paypal application live mode is enabled or not?

Answer (score 2):

Following are checklist you should verify, probably following is the basic reasons for an error.

> 1: Be sure the merchant account has Pro permissions. Also, be sure the
>   app has gone through the developer-approval process.
>
> 2: Also, be sure the app has been approved. The app has basic
>   permissions until you submit it for approval.
>
> 3: You may have a Business account but to accept credit card payments
>   in the live environment your account must be approved for Paypal.
>
> 4: You should contact PayPal Developer Support. File a ticket at
>   PayPal merchant technical Support. Click on the Contact Technical
>   Support link to file a ticket.
>
> 5: You can call to PayPal Customer Care, They will verify your name,
>   DOB, Verification Code (Code will be shown in your PayPal Dashboard in
>   Customer support page) etc, they will fix your issue in a minute or
>   they will help you to fix your issue.

Comment: n1. Merchant account has to be Pro to run direct credit card payments in the live environment. Application needs to be registered and approved by PayPal too

Comment: I think that the app is approved because The paypal account payment works successfully. I have the problem with direct credit card payment only.

Comment: @LucaSantaniello: then please review 3rd step

Comment: PayPay has approvated my account

Comment: @LucaSantaniello still you may find an issues in paypal?

Comment: @LucaSantaniello ciao Luca, how did you fix this issue?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I didn't understand how solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience to solve this issue I had to subscribe to the Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution.

There is no setup fee but there is a monthly fee and a transaction fee.

Setup link for Australia: 　https://www.paypal-apac.com/hss/au/