# Payment Failed " The merchant does not accept payments of this type"

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I successfully integrated Paypal in my android app using Paypal Android SDK and it really worked perfectly fine in the sandbox mode both the Paypal account holder and the non-Paypal account holder/credit card payment option. Now, when I switch to Live/Production mode, only the Paypal account holder option is working and it says "*The merchant does not accept payments of this type*" when I tried to the credit card option.

[See image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqUeP.jpg)

Comment: Try to include logs so that others can understand the issue. It might actually contain error code that would quickly solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Their is noting with the log maybe because the issue was not in the implementation of the code. I suspect that maybe their was some kind of restriction in the developer's account of my paypal but I don't know how to contact the support.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate issue you can check this

[Paypal returns "The merchant does not accept payments of this type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765987/paypal-returns-the-merchant-does-not-accept-payments-of-this-type)

You can also refers a Payment official github issue from here

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/104

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I have checked your solution. But how did you get an approval to paypal account, as our account was already been approved as a business paypal pro but we are still having that error. Thanks.